# Disable Hibernate 2nd level caches at runtime

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to disable Hibernate's 2nd level cache for some entities at runtime?

A lot of our entities have caching enabled but I suspect that in some cases the cache does not add much benefit or is even adversely affecting performance. I'd like to experiment with different settings without having to do a deployment every time.

Since this is only meant for experiments I wouldn't mind a solution that use Hibernate Internals or reflection to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving this was actually quite straight forward. The following code can be used to toggle the second-level cache for entities at runtime:

```
@Slf4j
@UtilityClass
public class HibernateUtil {

    public static void disableCache(EntityManager em, String entityName) {
        toggleCache(em, entityName, false);
    }

    public static void enableCache(EntityManager em, String entityName) {
        toggleCache(em, entityName, true);
    }

    private static void toggleCache(EntityManager em, String entityName, boolean enableCache) {
        final Optional<EntityPersister> persister = getEntityPersister(em, entityName);
        persister.ifPresentOrElse(p -> {
            log.info("Toggling cache for '{}': {}", entityName, enableCache);
            ClassUtil.writeField(p, "canReadFromCache", enableCache);
            ClassUtil.writeField(p, "canWriteToCache", enableCache);
        }, () -> log.warn("Entity '{}' could not be found", entityName));
    }

    private static Optional<EntityPersister> getEntityPersister(EntityManager em, String entityName) {
        final MetamodelImplementor model = (MetamodelImplementor) em.getMetamodel();
        final Collection<EntityPersister> persisters = model.entityPersisters().values();
        return persisters.stream().filter(e -> e.getEntityName().equalsIgnoreCase(entityName))
                .findFirst();
    }
}
```